How can I get eyeball to follow cursor?
Currently the entire eye follows the mouse cursor, but the pupil doesn't move. I'd like just the eyeball to follow.
I've modified the code of a tutorial that I followed. Instead of two eyes, there is one. Instead of circles for eyes, I created a more oval-shaped eye. Here's the html, css, and javascript I have so far.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>ISS Position</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", eyeball);
      function eyeball() {
        const eye = document.querySelector(".eye");
        let x = eye.getBoundingClientRect().left + eye.clientWidth / 2;
        let y = eye.getBoundingClientRect().top + eye.clientHeight / 2;
        let radian = Math.atan2(event.clientX - x, event.clientY - y);
        let rot = radian * (180 / Math.PI) * -1 + 270;
        eye.style.transform = `rotate(${rot}deg)`;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the ISS Locater</h1>
    <div class="eye-container">
      <div class="eye">
        <div class="pupil"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="lat">Latitude</label>
      <input id="lat" type="text" placeholder="<%= lat %>" name="Latitude" />
      <label for="lon">Longitude</label>
      <input id="lon" type="text" placeholder="<%= lon %>" name="Longitude" />
      <h2>Click the link below to see where it is now on a map</h2>
      <a
        href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=<%= lat %>,<%= lon %>"
        >Current ISS Location</a
      >
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
label {
  color: white;
}
h2 {
  color: white;
}
.eye-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.eye {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 80% 10%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.eye:before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import axios from 'axios';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json");
        const result = response;
        const lat = result.data.iss_position.latitude;
        const lon = result.data.iss_position.longitude;
        res.render("index.ejs", { lat: lat, lon: lon }); 
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.response.data);
        res.status(500).send("Failed to fetch random activity.");
    } 
});



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


In the eyeball function, in the line let radian = Math.atan2(event.clientX - x, event.clientY - y); you are accessing a event binding that does not exist in your code. Did you look into the browser's console already? It should mention that. To fix it, add a event parameter to the function: function eyeball(event) {

@Davi I see that now. Thanks for pointing that out. However, when I add event, nothing changes. I still have the same problem.

You aren't seeing pupil as it has no CSS giving it dimension or color or shape. However, the code you have used seems to have put a pupil within the eye using a before pseudo element. Which is it that you want to move? I imagine it's the existing pseudo element as that looks like a pupil, but I can't be sure, particularly since I think  you may be using the word 'eyeball' for pupil in the question (?)

@AHaworth I realize the pupil div wasn't given any color or shape. I created that when I was trying different things, but forgot and left it in there. To clarify, I'd like the the before pseudo element to move around inside the eye div and follow the cursor. Sorry for the confusion.

I also realize that, after playing with the code, the pupil does move; it just rotates inside the eye, but that is not what I'm after. What I'd like is for the pupil to move around inside the eye, toward the cursor.

So, basically, rotation is not relevant at all here? Just moving x and y directions, and only the pseudo element. You'll need to use CSS variables to position it via JS.

Like @AHaworth said, use positioning in your Javascript instead of rotating.
In this code snippet, I changed a few things:

Use your .pupil div instead of .eye:before (styled similarly)
Replace your .eye rotate Javascript code with movement of .pupil

See "EDIT" comments for more details of the changes from your original code.


document.addEventListener("mousemove", eyeball);

function eyeball() {
  const eye = document.querySelector(".eye");
  let x = eye.getBoundingClientRect().left + eye.clientWidth / 2;
  let y = eye.getBoundingClientRect().top + eye.clientHeight / 2;
  let radian = Math.atan2(event.clientX - x, event.clientY - y);
  // EDIT
  // eye.style.transform = `rotate(${rot}deg)`;

  // EDIT
  const pupils = document.querySelectorAll(".pupil");
  let newX = Math.sin( radian ) * 25
  let newY = Math.cos( radian ) * 10
  for( let pupil of pupils ) {
    pupil.style.left = newX + 30 + "px"
    pupil.style.top = newY + 15 + "px"
  }
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
label {
  color: white;
}
h2 {
  color: white;
}
.eye-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* EDIT Don't rotate, it breaks the position from Javascript */
  /* transform: rotate(45deg); */
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.eye {
  background-color: white;
  /* EDIT Change width and border shape, since we aren't rotating */
  margin: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
/* EDIT No longer using :before */
/* .eye:before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} */

/* EDIT - add pupil settings (simmilar to .eye:before) */
.pupil {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* top and left will be set by Javascript */
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
<div class="eye-container">
  <div class="eye">
    <div class="pupil"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- EDIT 2 -->
  <div class="eye">
    <div class="pupil"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <label for="lat">Latitude</label>
  <input id="lat" type="text" placeholder="<%= lat %>" name="Latitude" />
  <label for="lon">Longitude</label>
  <input id="lon" type="text" placeholder="<%= lon %>" name="Longitude" />

  <h2>Click the link below to see where it is now on a map</h2>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=<%= lat %>,<%= lon %>">Current ISS Location</a>
</div>



